# Local variable inside linked movieclip (from library) seems to reset to default state

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I didn't touch Actionscript in years but this blows my mind... It *should* be fairly easy, though.

Ok, I created a simple test scenario. I have a MovieClip in my Library named "mcTest". It's a simple square with the following actionscript on frame 1 (the only frame).

```
var test = false;

function setTest() {
  test = true;
  trace(test);
}

this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click_handler);

function click_handler(e:MouseEvent) {
  trace(test);
}
```

On the stage (frame 1, also the only frame) I have the following code:

```
var objTest:MovieClip = new mcTest();
objTest.setTest();
addChild(objTest);
```

When the project runs, the console gives me the expected "True". After clicking on the MovieClip, I get the unexpected "False". As if the variable was reset. What's going on? If I remove "objTest.setTest();" from the main stage and simply add the line "setTest();" inside the MovieClip itself, it gives the expected "True" when clicking on the MovieClip.

Btw, I'll move on to Class based approached with nicely typed variables and functions soon, but for now I stick with what I know ;)

**Update**:

Strange, when I modify the first line inside mcTest like this:

```
var test;
```

Or like this:

```
var test:Boolean;
```

The code works like expected. It seems that I shouldn't initialize my variable (and in well written code, use the constructor for that purpose of course)

Still, I don't understand why. If I remember correctly, the initial setup should work with older versions of Flash/Actionscript.

Just for my understanding; if anyone knows what is going on, please update me.

Comment: what happens when you put `trace(this)` in the handler?

Comment: trace(this) within the click_handler gives: 
[object mcTest]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In setTest, you are declaring a new local variable named `test` which is why it is not saving.

```
var test = false;

function setTest(){
    trace(test); //will return undefined

}
```

Why? Because your code is in a movieclip. The `var test = false` code hasn't actually executed when it wasn't added to the stage (as the code only executes when the frame is executed, which has to be after it is added to the stage **and** a frame has to pass.

To test, have this in frame 1:

```
var objTest:MovieClip = new mcTest();
addChild(objTest);
trace(objTest.test); //undefined
```

Have this in frame 2:

```
trace(objTest.test);
```

The result will be `undefined` and then `false`.

Comment: Ah! That clarifies it! It makes total sense. Thank you very much for your explanation